# animation issues when editing a uitableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

This is really simple, though still driving my nuts. I have a uitableview where I am trying to animate transition in and out of editing mode. This is what I took from an example that I have seen. It does do the job, but without the animation.

Any thoughts?

```
- (IBAction) EditTable:(id)sender
{

if(self.editing)
{
    [super setEditing:NO animated:YES]; 
    [tblSimpleTable setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    [tblSimpleTable reloadData];
    [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
    [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain];
}
else
{
    [super setEditing:YES animated:YES]; 
    [tblSimpleTable setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    [tblSimpleTable reloadData];
    [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"];
    [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone];
}

}
```

PS: I am also not sure why I need this line: [super setEditing:NO animated:YES]; but things just dont seem to work at all without it. I just saw a few examples online that dont do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you should not reloadData when set editing property.

BTW, What's your "super" class? Normally you don't have to invoke [super setEditing:YES animated:YES];

Comment: mysteriously that did it....still not sure why I need [super setEditing:YES animated:YES];

Comment: If you post more codes about your class, we can help you find out why you need call your super class's method. Maybe start another question is better than talk about it here, too.

Comment: I just had a similar problem in Swift with my table view, and removing a reloadData at the end of the setEditing function (after the tableView.beginUpdates and endUpdates) also worked for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it only the button that isn't animating properly?  Either way you should probably be using super.editButtonItem instead of your own; it's animated and just setting the text and style like that (I believe) isn't.  As far as calling the super, are you overriding one of the editing methods and not calling the super method from within there?  And xuzhes's answer about the reloadData is, I believe, correct as well.

Comment: whats not animating is the shift of all the cells right and left when clicking on "edit" or "done". It does work now, but I have no idea why it doesnt work when I removing the super call. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

@Implementation YourViewController // This can (should) be a subclass of UITableViewController to make your life easier

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem; // Automatically calls setEditing:animated: and changes itself to "Edit"/"Done" between presses
}

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if (editing == YES) {
        // Do stuff here
    } else {
        // Do stuff here
    }

    // Reload all sections of the table view
    // THIS IS THE PART YOU'RE INTERESTED IN
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0,[self.tableView numberOfSections]);
    NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range];
    [self.tableView reloadSections:indexSet withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

Check out the documentation for comments on the methods from Apple :)